# How to set and get Ids on click on google stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have configured the Google stacked column chart as well, Now I have to show some data on click, but on click i need to know which stack i have clicked.

**So I want to set id`enter code here`s for each stack and want to get that id on click.**

I need the solution on below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding event handler to the chart.

Please go through below code for same.

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];

    if (selectedItem) {
        var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
        var year = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        alert('The user selected ' + value + ', Year :' + year);
    }
}

// Listen for the 'select' event, and call my function selectHandler() when
// the user selects something on the chart.
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddqtv1vs/) for your quick reference.

Comment: You can access the data easily as you mentioned, But I want to set ID for its row or column, My scanario is that I have report data managed in divs, I want to show that on click, so i have to set dive ids and i will get that ids to show divs. I.E i want to save id "12-Nescafe-Instant", If i refer to our jsfiddle example. thanks for your kind response